Working with Eureka Server and Eureka Discovery Client and OCI Java SDK in Spring boot (Maven Project)
I'm having problem trying to get microservice with Eureka and OCI Java SDK.
Any idea how to make at least the application running when trying to use both maven repository.
I've tried to use these in the pom.xml
Eureka Discovery Client
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>

OCI AI Document SDK:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.oci.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>oci-java-sdk-aidocument</artifactId>
    <version>3.39.1</version>
</dependency>

And I am able to run it properly, but getting this error:
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No http provider available; add dependency on one of the oci-java-sdk-common-httpclient-* choices, e.g. oci-java-sdk-common-httpclient-jersey

When trying to run the analyze document using the SDK.
